# IIS Management Console is not present in web management tool

Tags: iis, console, iis-7

IIS Management console is not present under web management tool. Two options are there:

1. IIS 6 management compatibility
2. IIS Management Scripts & Tools.

I have checked both, but it did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Windows 7 since you specified IIS 7.

The IIS Management Console should be available under Control Panel → Administrative Tools.

If it's not there, verify you have IIS installed under Control Panel → Programs and Features → "Turn Windows features on or off".